# Unknown space in top of website in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, space

There is an unknown space on top of my website only in Firefox. There is not nothing like this when I browse it in Chrome, IE, Opera, etc.
This is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="line"></div>
<div id="top">
```

and this is my CSS:

```
html {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}

body {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size:8pt;
    color:#333;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
}

#line {
    height:8px;
    background-color:#333333;
    clear:none
}
```

As you see there is nothing before `<div id="line"></div>` that is a line with dark gray color in the picture.
What is this unknown space?
[image]

Comment: I tested with jsfiddle and it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ThbxM/2/ (Firefox 16.0.2)

Comment: You are right @ianaz. It works well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There was a HTML output in my config file that I was called before `<html>` tag.